# Catch 404 error from BufferedInputStream

Tags: java, html, error-handling

I have a function for html page download.
Here is the code:

```
public class pageDownload {
    public static void down(final String filename, final String urlString)
            throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        BufferedInputStream in = null;
        FileOutputStream fout = null;
        try {
            in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(urlString).openStream());
            fout = new FileOutputStream(new File(filename));
            final byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            int count;
            while ((count = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
                fout.write(data, 0, count);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.err.println("IndexOutOfBoundsException: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        in.close();
        fout.close();
    }
}
```

Works ok, problem appears when i try to download a page that not exist. I can't figure out how to handle 404 error in this case.
Has anyone some idea?

Comment: How do yo call this method? give an example with a page that works and one that doesn't

Comment: Like this : pageDownload.down(newPath+"\\out.html",links.get(i)); First parameter is where the page is saved and the secound the link. For the first element in the list (http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/12-2a-the-override-and-final-specifiers-and-covariant-return-types/) and the second (http://riweb.tibeica.com/tests/l1_absolute?id=1) doesn't work.

Comment: For the first link works ok (download the page) for the second give me this errors:**Caught IOException: http://riweb.tibeica.com/tests/l1_absolute?id=1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at project.pageDownload.down(pageDownload.java:37)
 at project.Main.main(Main.java:60)**

Comment: Yep the IOException is caught in the `catch (IOException e)` block and is printed - then the program continues to `in.close();` but the `in` is still null, hence the NPE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this? I added a finally to save close the Streams

```
public class pageDownload {
    public static void down(final String filename, final String urlString)
    throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

        BufferedInputStream in = null;
        FileOutputStream fout = null;
        try {
            in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(urlString).openStream());
            fout = new FileOutputStream(new File(filename));

            final byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            int count;
            while ((count = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
                fout.write(data, 0, count);
            }
        } catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            System.err.println("Caught 404: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            System.err.println("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
        {
            System.err.println("IndexOutOfBoundsException: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        finally{
            if(in != null)
                try { in.close(); } catch ( IOException e ) { }
            if(fout != null)
                try { fout.close(); } catch ( IOException e ) { }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Yes. That was the problem. Thank you very much. :D

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you get a NullPointerException when you try to close the streams. You should anyway close them in a finally clause or use [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

```
public static void down(final String filename, final String urlString)
        throws IOException {
    try (BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(urlString)
            .openStream());
         FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(new File(filename))) {
        final byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        int count;
        while ((count = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
            fout.write(data, 0, count);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.err.println("IndexOutOfBoundsException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```